# How to find number of repeated users in pig

Tags: apache-pig

So, I have the following data in hdfs.

```
user_id, category_id
1, 12344
1, 12344
1, 12345
2, 12345
2, 12345
3, 12344
3, 12344
```

and so on.. I want to find number of repeated users each category got..

so, in example above..

```
12344, 2 (because user_id 1 and 3 are repeated users)
12345, 1 (user_id 2 is repeated user.. 1 is not as that user visited just once)
```

How do I do this in pig?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first try to keep only the repeated users, and then apply grouping and counting them will end up in solution .. Please try as per below code

Input :

```
1,12344
1,12344
1,12345
2,12345
2,12345
3,12344
3,12344
```

Pig Script :

```
 records = LOAD '/home/inputfiles/repeats.txt' USING PigStorage(',') AS(id:int,category:int);

records_grp = GROUP records BY (id,category);

records_each = FOREACH records_grp  GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS(id,category), (COUNT(records.id) >1 ?'Y' : 'N') as repeat_ind;

records_filter = FILTER records_each BY repeat_ind == 'Y';

rec_grp  = GROUP records_filter BY category;

rec_each = FOREACH rec_grp GENERATE group as category, COUNT(records_filter) as cnt_of_repeated_users;

dump rec_each;
```

Output:

```
(12344,2)
(12345,1)
```